# Simplify this process for reading a text file with values joined by special delimiter

Tags: c#, csv

Could somebody suggest a better solution, yet not too complex as I am still fresh, to my lengthly one please? 
i.e. read a text file with values joined by a special delimiter and output into a csv

Txt file:

```
one¬two¬thr,ee¬four
two¬three¬fo,ur¬five
```

Expected outcome:

```
one, two, thr,ee, four
two, three, fo,ur, five
```

each value should sit in it's own column, but can have commas, treat delimiter like a column

Code:

```
// main method    

     var txtFile = File.ReadAllLines("test.txt");
     var meta = new List<string>();

     foreach (var line in txtFile)
                {
                    var first = line.Substring(0, GetNthIndex(line,'¬',1));
                    var second = line.Substring(GetNthIndex(line, '¬', 1) + 1, GetNthIndex(line, '¬', 2) - GetNthIndex(line, '¬', 1) - 1);
                    var third = line.Substring(GetNthIndex(line, '¬', 2) + 1, GetNthIndex(line, '¬', 3) - GetNthIndex(line, '¬', 2) - 1);
                    var fourth = line.Substring(line.LastIndexOf('¬') + 1);

                    meta.Add("\"" + first + "\"" + "," + "\"" + second + "\"" + "," + "\"" + third + "\"", + "," + "\"" + fourth + "\"");
                }

                File.WriteAllLines("meta.csv",meta);


// outside main method

    public static int GetNthIndex(string l, char c, int n)
            {
              int counter = 0;
              for (var i = 0; i < l.Length; i++)
              {
                  if (l[i] == c)
                  {
                      counter++;
                      if (counter == n)
                      {
                          return i;
                      }
                  }
              }
              return -1;
            }
```

Appreciate all responses

Comment: `string.Split`?  But really you might want to look for a CSV parser, they can handle different delimiters.

Comment: Display the desired out put as well

Comment: @juharr thanks will try with string.Split. p.s. i am doing this more as an exercise to learn, so don't want want to use any external libraries

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to do that, you have to:

1. Read all lines from "test.txt".
2. Split each line by '¬'.
3. Join the split result by your new delimiter, comma. Notice that you have to pad each cell* with "
4. Write the new lines to "meta.csv".

* **[string.Join](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/57a79xd0(v=vs.110).aspx)** concatenates all the elements of a string array, using the specified separator between each element. The delimiter in our case is a comma (,), padded by double quotes (") from both sides. Don't forget to pad the result string with double quotes from both sides again. For example: given a list of [x1,x2,x3], the result would be "x1","x2","x3", as the delimiter is "," and we padded the result with additional quotes from both sides.

Try this:

```
List<string> lLines = File.ReadAllLines("test.txt").Select(line => "\"" + string.Join("\",\"", line.Split('¬')) + "\"").ToList();
File.WriteAllLines("meta.csv", lLines);
```

Or a simpler solution without LINQ:

```
string[] aLines = File.ReadAllLines("test.txt");
List<string> lMeta = new List<string>();
foreach (string sLine in aLines)
{
    string[] aItems = sLine.Split('¬');
    lMeta.Add("\"" + string.Join("\",\"", aItems) + "\"");
}
File.WriteAllLines("meta.csv", lMeta);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `string.Split` and `string.Join`. Here is my take

```
var txtFile = File.ReadAllLines("test.txt");
var meta = new List<string>();
foreach (var line in txtFile)
{
    var values = line.Split(new[] { '¬' });
    meta.Add(string.Join(",", values.Select(v => "\"" + v + "\"")));
}
File.WriteAllLines("meta.csv", meta);
```

Comment: Or as one line `File.WriteAllLines("meta.csv", File.ReadLines("test.txt").Select(line => string.Join(",", line.Split('¬').Select(v => $"\"{v}\""))))`.

Comment: Thanks Justin, this for sure looks much better! but could you by any chance simplify your solution to not use linq please? as i am a newb and haven't reached that stage of learning yet :(